# Can someone help translate the Russian Cursive in the image below

Tags: словоупотребление

[image]

The below image was listed in a book a wishes and I was hoping someone could help me translate it.  I think it begins with "Want a new year to start...."  but can't figure out the rest.

Comment: Возможно, русская фраза такая: *Хочу, чтобы новый год начался лучше предыдущих.*

Comment: i was conflicted about `преДыдущих`, the letter at the position of the 1st `g` looks like `в`, and `ы` look like `e`

Comment: Thank you so much!  So do you think it is translated:   "I want the new year to start better than the previous ones"

Comment: Да, Justin T, я думаю, что эту фразу можно перевести именно так.

Comment: Согласен, Баян Купи-ка, написание двух этих букв вызывает сомнение. Но других интерпретаций последнего слова в этой фразе я не вижу.

Comment: could be an absent minded typo of the author, `преве` instead of `преды`

Comment: I think so too.

Comment: Looks like "превядущих" – that can be interference with another language, perhaps a Slavic one that has it that way, not like the Standard Russian "предыдущих". Or that can well be an extrapolation of a Russian learner, who's never seen the word "предыдущий".

Comment: Эти варианты нельзя исключить, Желтое небо.

Comment: I would support the typo claim, because also `новый год` in the image reads  `новыХ` for me.